# Remove whitespace from an array of string

Tags: java, arrays, string

Remove whitespace from an array of string.

While creating an array of string from a sentence, I'm encountering multiple spaces and need to remove them in order to create a new reverse sentence from the given sentence. How do I remove extra spaces in the middle of two words?
Example: `a good   example`
How do I remove two spaces in between *good* and *example* ?

Here is the code I'm using:

```java
public class reverseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "a good   example";
        String ans = revString(s);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    static String revString(String s) {
        String[] arr = s.split(" ");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (arr[i] == null) {
                continue;
            } else {
                ans.append(arr[i].trim());
                // ans.append(" ");
            }
        }
        String is = ans.toString();
        return is.trim();
    }
}
```

The expected output was: `example good a`
The output I'm getting is: `example   good a`
Comparing the string at the I-th index with " " should result in continuation of the loop. Instead it jumps to the *else* condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) (of class `java.lang.String`) is a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Just add a `+` (i.e. "plus" symbol – which means *one or more*) to the value of the parameter.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "a good   example";
        String ans = revString(s);
        System.out.println(ans);

    }

    static String revString(String s) {
        String[] arr = s.split(" +"); // CHANGE HERE - added '+'
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (arr[i] == null) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                ans.append(arr[i].trim());
                ans.append(" ");
            }
        }
        String is = ans.toString();
        return is.trim();
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
example good a
```

Comment: thank you so much. Spent a lot of time figuring this one out